# Как сделать анимацию пульсирующей кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать анимацию как тут? https://amazing-rp.ru/
"Начать играть"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как называется эффект, не обязательно давать решение.
Работаю пока без JQ на чистом JS.

P.S. Пробовал гуглить "Пульсирующая кнопка", но это не то, что нужно

Comment: Это на чистом `css` тоже можно реализовать, `JS или JQ` тут не не за чем...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это простая `CSS` анимация, подробно с примерами [ТУТ](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

```css
.button{
width: 200px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.88);
    color: #e6a833;
    -webkit-animation-name: 'play_down';
    -moz-animation-name: 'play_up';
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes  play_top {

 0% 
 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(0,163,182,.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(0,163,182,.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(0,163,182,.6);
 }
 to 
 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0,163,182,0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0,163,182,0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0,163,182,0);
 }   

}

@keyframes  play_down {

 0% 
 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(55,55,55,.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(55,55,55,.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(55,55,55,.6); 
 }
 to 
 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(55,55,55,0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(55,55,55,0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(55,55,55,0);  
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="button"><h1>Кнопка</h1></div>
```

Comment: `-webkit-keyframes` Оскорбление чувств пользователей Firefox!

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 141, 1, .7);
  animation: shadow 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(55, 141, 250, .8);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(55, 141, 250, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```